# Is it acceptable practice to wrap a table row with a form?

Tags: html

..It feels like it shouldnt be, but yet it works.

For instance:

```
    <table>
    .....

    <form action='/foo'>
    <tr>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
    <td><input type='submit' value='bar'>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
```

However if you have a table with multiple forms, is there a better way to do this?

Just asking out of curiosity really.

Note: I have also seen some big companies have forms in large tables where there are hidden input fields at the top, and they get populated automatically via javascript and submitted with extra data from that row.  This also seems messy and over-complicated.

Comment: I believe this is against HTML specifications, but if it works why not :)

Comment: @Pietu1998 Heh, yeah I know.  Just wondering if anyone had a better way, this feels flakey to me.

Comment: @Pietu1998: the obvious answer to that is that in the future there is no reason why it should work and indeed reason why it shouldn't if browsers start adhering to the standards better. For example It would be valid to interpret that as an implicit close table before the form, an implicit open table between the form and tr, etc. which would potentially screw up loads of stuff. The script method seems more robust to me.

Comment: I prefer one form and scripts work for the logic. It makes HTML clean and logic is easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's invalid markup.

From the [HTML 4.01 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
```

Here, `(%block;|SCRIPT)+` means that a form element can only contain scripts and block elements, where `%block` is defined as

```
<!ENTITY % block
   "P | %heading; | %list; | %preformatted; | DL | DIV | NOSCRIPT |
    BLOCKQUOTE | FORM | HR | TABLE | FIELDSET | ADDRESS">
```

In other words, you can wrap a form around a table, but not a table row.